# C#, how do i get an ip address, from a TcpClient?

Tags: c#

C#, how do i get an ip address, from a TcpClient?

```
I have a TcpClient and i want to get it's name.
```

Comment: you will usually have 2 adresses, yours and the 'other' (server). which one do you need?

Comment: When you have an answer that satisfies your question, you should click the accept checkmark beside it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want the remote end point:

```
IPEndPoint ipep = (IPEndPoint)myTcpClient.RemoteEndPoint;
IPAddress ipa = ipep.Address;
```

Answer (score 3):

Say you have a `TcpClient` instance called `MyTcpClient`.

```
private string IPAddress
{
    get
    {
        IPEndPoint ep = MyTcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
        if (ep == null)
            return "unknown";
        return ep.Address.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case what you need is the local address instead you can use LocalEndPoint instead of RemoteEndPoimt in the previous replies.